# Brush selection in Box plot(d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot, brush

Is there any option for brush selection in box plot in d3.js?

like the selection in the following link

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/splom.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

D3 isn't a charting library, so it doesn't expose things like the brush control as an option, but instead as a configurable component. You can use [`d3.svg.brush()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush) to attach a brush control to any visualization, including settings for what scales to use and handlers defining what actions to perform before, during, and after the brushing event.